# Consume WCF Service in windows 8.1 mobile app developement

Tags: c#, mobile

I am creating windows 8.1 mobile application where i want to consume WCF service.
I know how to call Webservice from windows 8.1,simply we call the url of webservice.
for ex: `http://192.168.0.102/MobilApp/SrvOMM.asmx/FunCheckLogin?username=abc&password=abc`
above url we call through http client and it call and return the result same thing I want to call in WCF service.

I have created WCF service and checked it in Test Client its working fine.
when i am creating url as we create for web service and hitting it, it returns an error.

I am unaware of WCF web.config settings like endpoints,service behaviour and etc. if is there anything we need to mention in configuration file please let me know.

Just wanted step by step process to consume WCF service in windows 8.1 mobile app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consuming a WCF service in windows 8/8.1 can be done. See this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx